# Android Unicode Gender Symbols

Tags: android, unicode

I'm trying to print the male and female symbols in an Android TextView.  In the preview of the layout, it works just fine.  But when I run the application on my phone, they are replaced by blue and pink images.  How can I override this so it just displays them as basic text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For maximum compatibility you will need to find a font/typeface (.ttf file) that supports these unicode characters.

Once you find said file, place it in the assets folder in fonts/typeface_file.ttf

Then you load the Typeface:

```
Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "fonts/typeface_file.ttf");
```

Next apply it to your TextView:

```
textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

The advantage to loading your own typeface is that it won't matter what the system font of the device is, it will always be available and include those unicode characters because it is packaged into your app.